# Android Platform Guide trouble with adding a platform through the command line

Tags: configuration, cordova, installation

I am following the installation guide:  http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

As aa early info this is my issue.

```
C:\apps\hello>cordova platform add android
[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
Command failed to execute : ant jar
```

This is what i did:

- I installed all Java Dev packages (everything)
- I installed Apache ANT, and created the environment variables (they work)
- I created environment variables for PATH for the adt-bundle

All i want is to

```
cordova platform add android

cordova emulate android
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the JRE instead of the JDK... Im no expert on Java installations, but this was my error.

Comment: I had to set a JAVA_HOME environment variable per the answer from King.

Comment: I dont understand.. why are you commenting on my answer which was the right thing in my case?

Answer (score 4):

This is due to ANT tools could not find **tools.jar** in JRE lib directory. When I copied **tools.jar** from JDK lib directory to JRE lib directory, the problem was absolutely solved and the build was successful when I ran the command "**cordova -d platform add android**". Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue today. upon research I found that I need to install JDK instead of JRE.

[Install JDK from this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

After installation, set the JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 [your JDK Path].

Hope this helps!!