# PhoneGap 3.0 Android build Command failed to execute : ant jar

Tags: android, ant, cordova, jar

I installed PhoneGap 3.0 with Node.js and configured all the environment variables so that javac, java, and ant all work but when I do a basic app create and try to build it for Android, I get the following error:

An error occurred during creation of android sub-project. Creating Cordova project for the Android platform: Command failed to execute : ant jar

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188659/android-platform-guide-trouble-with-adding-a-platform-through-the-command-line

Comment: Thank you but I already tried that and that isn't the issue. The JDK is installed correctly.

Comment: Also, some extra info is that I just tried it on my Windows 8 laptop and had no problems - this is something specific to my Windows 7 desktop.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure you have the Android Build Tools installed for your Android SDK version. In the Android SDK manager under Tools>Android SDK Build-tools you should see that the Build tools for your SDK version are not installed.

Detail on how I uncovered this:

---

To identify this as the root cause I ran the Cordova command with -d for verbosity:

```
cordova -d platform add android
```

The output of this command shows the error:

```
Running bin/create for platform "android" with command: ""C:\Users\---\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\bin\create"  "C:\Users\---\workspace_android\FleetView\platforms\android" "com.---.fleetview" "Fleet View"" (output to follow)
```

Running the offending command directly:

```
"C:\Users\---\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\bin\create"  "C:\Users\---\workspace_android\FleetView\platforms\android" "com.---.fleetview" "Fleet View"
```

produces this output:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:479: SDK does not have any Build Tools installed.

Total time: 1 second
Command failed to execute : ant jar
```

I am on Windows 7.

Comment: Wow! That was it! Thank you very much Pherris. I could not find an answer to this anywhere and I really appreciate your thoroughly explained answer.

Comment: Error can be caused also if you are referencing into app-support library from Eclipse studio. Copy of the jar files into libs folder helped me solved this problem.

Answer (score 7):

This is due to ANT tools could not find **tools.jar** in JRE lib directory. When I copied **tools.jar** from JDK lib directory to JRE lib directory, the problem was absolutely solved and the build was successful when I ran the command "**cordova -d platform add android**". Hope this helps you.

Posted the answer to similar question: [Android Platform Guide trouble with adding a platform through the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188659/android-platform-guide-trouble-with-adding-a-platform-through-the-command-line?lq=1)

Comment: This was helpful to me so thanks, but could you please briefly explain why this solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A combination of 2 things [worked for me](http://softwaregosh.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/compiling-phonegap-hello-world-to.html):

- include the JDK in your path (path\to\jdk\bin of course)
- exclude the JRE from your path (or at least have it come *after* the JDK)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, 
I was having jdk-6 and I updated to jdk-7, 
 
that fixed the issue, 
Also I didn't installed ant in the first place,
in your case ant PATH might be missing. 
See if that helps.