# phonegap run android: command failed to execute: ant jar - on Windows

Tags: android, ant, cordova

When I am trying to add the android platform to a new phonegap project(3.1.0) I get the following error:

```
  Checking Android requirements...
    Creating android project...
    [Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:

    Command failed to execute : ant jar
```

I did a lot of research and tried a lot of potential solutions that did not work. So my last hope is Stackoverflow.

- I am using Java jdk 1.7.0_45 (also tried the JRE) which is properly installed
- I am using ant 1.9.2 where I'm perfectly able to check the version of ant in the command line. The only problem here is that `ant jar` gives me a build.xml error. I think this is the main cause why I get the  `Command failed to execute : ant jar` error.
- I installed phonegap and cordova throughout node and those work perfectly as well.
- My paths are all configured properly.

I dont know what to do, I need to know a way to get a proper build.xml. I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484898/phonegap-3-0-android-build-command-failed-to-execute-ant-jar

Comment: I saw that article. Going to try the the suggested solution again. Ty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ANT tools could not find tools.jar in JRE lib directory.

In order to solve your issue just :

**Copy** tools.jar from Java/JDK1.7.0_45/lib directory to Java/JRE7/lib directory and
**Run** the command `cordova platform add android` again.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This was indeed the thing that did the job a while ago. Will give you credits for your answer.