# Error in staring with cordova: Command failed to execute : ant jar

Tags: android, ant, cordova

Hello I was trying to create my first app with phonegap but when I run "**phonegap run android**" it throw me the error:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
Command failed to execute : ant jar
```

And when I use **cordova -d platform add android**:

```
Creating android project...
Running bin/create for platform "android" with command: ""C:\Users\Fernando\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\bin\create"  "C:\Users\Fernando\Desktop\phonegap_examples\hello_phonegap\platforms\androi
d" "com.phonegap.helloworld" "HelloWorld"" (output to follow)
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:

Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:

Command failed to execute : ant jar

    at C:\Users\Fernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:246:30
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:636:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:730:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:5)
```

In my path I added:

```
C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin;
C:\Program Files\adt_Android\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Program Files\adt_Android\sdk\tools
```

I dont know what I am missing, I searched about it but I didnt find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is posted on [phonegap run android: command failed to execute: ant jar - on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016990/phonegap-run-android-command-failed-to-execute-ant-jar-on-windows)

> ANT tools could not find tools.jar in JRE lib directory.
>
> In order to solve your issue just :
>
> Copy tools.jar from Java/JDK1.7.0_45/lib directory to Java/JRE7/lib
>   directory and Run the command cordova platform add android again.
>
> Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the jdk1.8/libs/tools.jar to ant/lib folder.